# Media query at screen with min width override all screen size and I can't get it to work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a sample html css with mobile first responsiveness, I added the roles for each screen size, however, the browsers only apply the query and ignore the original css rules, I have tried to re-arrange the css files in order to avoid overwrite but not working!

[image]

here is the HTML

```
 <section>
      <header>
        <img src="/assets/menu.svg" class="menu-btn">
        <p class="logo">John .Y</p>
      </header>
      <!-- <div id="section-content"></div> -->
      <div class="product-wrapper">
        <h1>Add Prod</h1>
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Date of Birth</label>
            <input />
          </div>
          <button>Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS where I change the input font size on width 700px, however it gets overridden to all screen widths

```
.product-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 80%;
}

form input,
label {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  display: block;
}

form label {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}

form input {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 5px solid var(--primary-color);
  outline: none;

}

form button {
  color: white;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 2.875em;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
  padding: 1.25em 1.25em 1.25em calc(2.5em + 1.5em);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}





@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .left-col {
    display: flex;

  }

  .content p {
    width: 70%;
  }

  form input,
  label {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

}
```

Comment: One thing you can be sure of is no one can help you solve your problem just looking at a screenshot, Edit your question and add the relevant code to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thanks Zohir! gonna re ask it with more code sample

Comment: Can you edit your question to only include the form element you reference in the screenshot? There's a ton of code to wade through. Also, there are no mobile-first styles for the `form` element in your example. And based on your screen shot, which appears to be different than the provided code, the styles look to be applying exactly as intended. The `grid-template-columns` over 700px is overwriting the default/mobile first value for that property.

Comment: Sure! I will be more specific

Comment: I grabbed your code so I could debug it and the issue isn't appearing for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce either, the media works as expected

Comment: Hi Dan & Zohir! Thank you so much! I think the problem was with the browser caching, I did pull the code into a new project and I cleared browser cache.